# How to get sibling text of element in span using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, siblings

I need to change a text in a span.

```
<span class="count_bottom">
    <i class="blue">
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
        12% 
    </i> 
    From last seen
</span>
```

I only need to change `From last seen` text according to button click event.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. If you haven't even tried anything, there's millions of jQuery tutorials out there and you definitely should do at least one of them.

Comment: why don't you wrap your text within some another `<span>` and give it unique class to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out non-empty text nodes inside space and then replace with new content.

```js
$('.count_bottom')
  // get all child nodes
  .contents()
  // filter out non-empty text node
  .filter(function() {
    // check node type and content
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length;
    // replace it with new content  
  }).replaceWith('new text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="blue"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>12% </i> From last seen</span>
```

---

With pure JavaScript

```js
// get the `i` tag inside `span`
document.querySelector('.count_bottom > i')
  // get adjacent text node which is immediately after the element
  .nextSibling
  // update text content of the text node
  .textContent = 'new text';
```

```html
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="blue"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>12% </i> From last seen</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first `i` element in `span` and use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to getting next sibling text of it.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".count_bottom > i")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "New value";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change text</button>
<span class="count_bottom">
    <i class="blue">
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
        12% 
    </i> 
    From last seen
</span>
```